# Get string between strings and loop through content in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop, html-parsing

The function below fetches only the first occurrence. In this case it returns: "John Smith jsmith@gmail.com", how do I get the other names with their corresponding Emails.

I appreciate your help.

```
<?php
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
{

    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}

////////////// CONTENT TO BE PARSED ///////////////////
$fullstring = 'Name: John Smith<br> Email: jsmith@google.com<br> Name: Perter Doe<br>Email: peterd@yahoo.com<br> Name: Nelly Denver<br> Email: neldenver@google.co.za<br>'; 

///////////////////////////////////

$parsed1 = get_string_between($fullstring, "Name:", "<br>");
$parsed2 = get_string_between($fullstring, "Email: ", "<br>");

$parsed = $parsed1.'<br>'.$parsed2.'<br>';

echo $parsed;

?>
```

Comment: There's no loop in your code, how could it return more than one occurrence?

Comment: Thank you Bamar for your quick response. I spent a good 2 days trying to figure out how to loop through it and could not figure it out.

Comment: Please show what you tried. How are we supposed to help you understand what you did wrong if you don't show it?

Comment: Thanks Bamar, I tried something like: foreach($parsed as $item)
{
print $item;
{

Comment: That makes no sense, `$parsed` isn't an array, it's a string. You need to loop in the `get_string_between()` function, looking for another match of the `$start` and `$end` strings after the previous match.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, the two gentlemen Shankar and Amal gave me a hand and I appreciate your feedback too.

Answer (score 2):

[`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) can only find the numeric position of the first occurrence and hence your function can't be used to find multiple occurences. You could use a regex with [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) to do this:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end) {
    $start = preg_quote($start);
    $end = preg_quote($end);
    $pattern = "~$start\s*(.*?)$end\s*~";
    $match = preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
    if ($match) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$parsed1 = get_string_between($fullstring, 'Name:', '<br>');
print_r($parsed1);

$parsed2 = get_string_between($fullstring, 'Email:', '<br>');
print_r($parsed2);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John Smith
    [1] => Perter Doe
    [2] => Nelly Denver
)
Array
(
    [0] => jsmith@google.com
    [1] => peterd@yahoo.com
    [2] => neldenver@google.co.za
)
```

Now, to print the names and emails, you can simply loop through the result arrays, like so:

```
$parsed1 = get_string_between($fullstring, 'Name:', '<br>');
$parsed2 = get_string_between($fullstring, 'Email:', '<br>');

for ($i=0; $i < count($parsed1); $i++) { 
    echo $parsed1[$i] . ' ' . $parsed2[$i] . '<br/>';
}
```

Output:

```
John Smith jsmith@google.com
Perter Doe peterd@yahoo.com
Nelly Denver neldenver@google.co.za
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/82414)

Comment: Thanks Amal, I'm going to try it now.

Comment: @user3111950: Sure. I've added a demo in my answer for easier understanding :)

Comment: I can't thank you enough, I appreciate your time. Please tell me if I need to give you a vote or something? I'm new to this forum!!

Comment: @user3111950: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can upvote this answer but it requires 15 reputation (you currently have 11). You can mark this answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) if it answers your question. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks, dude. It helped.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are trying to print the Name and Email values separately. So why don't you try something simpler like this ?

```
$fullstring = "Name: John Smith<br> Email: jsmith@google.com<br> Name: Perter Doe<br>Email: peterd@yahoo.com<br> Name: Nelly Denver<br> Email: neldenver@google.co.za<br>";
$arr=array_map('trim',array_filter(explode('<br>',$fullstring),'strlen'));

foreach($arr as $value)
{
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Name: John Smith
Email: jsmith@google.com
Name: Perter Doe
Email: peterd@yahoo.com
Name: Nelly Denver
Email: neldenver@google.co.za
```

If you don't need the `Name :` and `Email :` , just replace the below **`echo`** statement with the one inside the **`foreach`** construct.

```
 echo explode(' ',$value)[1]."<br>";
```

Comment: Thank you Shankar for your suggestion, but what I was trying to output is something like: John Smith jsmith@google.com Peter Doe peterd@yahoo.com Nelly Denver neldenver@google.co.za - I wanna leave out "Name:" and "Email:" and <br> in the first instance and leave out "Email:" and "<br>" in the second instance because I'm using them as delimeters. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes i know :) That's why i had added two scenarios of the code. Make use of the last `echo` statement and replace the existing one inside the `foreach`.

Comment: Thank you so so much Shankar, I promise I'm going to try your code. I'm trying Amal's at the moment (working great).

Answer (score 1):

This is how to loop finding all the matches:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end) {
    $last_end = 0;
    $matches = array();
    while (($ini = strpos($string, $start, $last_end)) !== false) {
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
        $matches[] = substr($string, $ini, $len);
        $last_end = $ini + $len + strlen($end);
    }
    return $matches;
}
```

It returns an array of all the strings between each start and end, you'll need to use a loop or `implode()` in the caller to print them.

Comment: Thanks, dude. It helped.